# Scraping (BeautifulSoap, Selenium) not possible for all DIVs?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

i try to scrape some information from a website - for most of the div-informations this works fine - but i have problem reading some specific DIVs. At first i only tried it with "normal" bs4-request - but then also with selenium - but i still get no data back...

Below you can find my full code.
It works fine with a response with this search:

```
tmpDiv = soup.find ("div", {"id": "financial-strength"})
```

But it is not working with this div:

```
tmpDiv = soup.find ("div", {"id": "analyst-estimate"})
```

It outputs only

```
<div class="children" data-v-39722e0c="" id="analyst-estimate" style="min- 
 height:200px;display:block;">
</div>
```

Below you can find the full (not working) code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys, os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

link = "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL/summary"
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
options = Options ()
options.add_argument ('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.get (link)
soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep (2)

page = requests.get (link)
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, 'html.parser')
# tmpDiv = soup.find ("div", {"id": "financial-strength"})
tmpDiv = soup.find ("div", {"id": "analyst-estimate"})
print(tmpDiv.prettify())
```

I heard this is probably a "lazy loading website" - but shouldn´t the selenium-access wait till the full site is loaded with all the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

There are two major things, why you wont get the result:

1. After requesting website with `selenium` you also requesting it with `requests` and assign the response to soup.
2. Data wont be loaded, if not needed, that is what you already figured out -->  "lazy loading website"

### How to fix that?

1. Remove all `requests` specific lines
2. Scroll the element you need into view, so that data is loading:

   ```
   element = driver.find_element_by_id("analyst-estimate")
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
   ```

**Example**

*Be aware, I added my webdriver path, so you have to edit it.*

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

link = "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL/summary"
driver = webdriver.Chrome ('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get (link)

time.sleep(2.5)

element = driver.find_element_by_id("analyst-estimate")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# tmpDiv = soup.find ("div", {"id": "financial-strength"})
tmpDiv = soup.find ("div", {"id": "analyst-estimate"})
print(tmpDiv.prettify())
```

**Output**

```html
<div class="children" data-v-39722e0c="" id="analyst-estimate" style="">
 <div class="capture-area">
  <h2 class="fs-large fc-primary fw-bolder">
   Analyst Estimate
  </h2>
  <table class="normal-table-mobile financial-strength-table">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
     </td>
     <td>
      Sep 2021
     </td>
     <td>
      Sep 2022
     </td>
     <td>
      Sep 2023
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Revenue (Mil $)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       313003.40
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       328872.10
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       341577.60
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      EBIT (Mil $)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       76803.87
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       81038.89
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       84830.53
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      EBITDA (Mil $)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       88706.60
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       92604.88
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       94034.53
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      EPS ($)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       3.94
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       4.28
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       4.55
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      EPS without NRI ($)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       3.97
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       4.27
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       4.55
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      EPS Growth Rate (%)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       10.04
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <!-- -->
     </td>
     <td>
      <!-- -->
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Dividends per Share ($)
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       0.74
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       0.82
      </span>
     </td>
     <td>
      <span>
       1.15
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works great - thank you very much! btw: Is there also a way to do this without selenium / chromedriver.exe?

Comment: Concerning your question may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983440/14460824